# can't extract data using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to pull an address name from the following page: https://property.spatialest.com/nc/durham/#/property/100016

`property_spider.py`:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from property.items import PropertyItem

class PropertySpider(Spider):
    name = "property"
    allowed_domains = ["property.spatialest.com"]
    start_urls = [ 
        "http://property.spatialest.com/nc/durham/#/property/100016"
    ]   

    def parse(self, response):
        address = Selector(response).xpath("//html/body/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/header/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span")

        address_item = PropertyItem()
        address_item['address'] = address.xpath('span[@class="value "]/text()').extract()
        yield address_item
```

The spider returns `{'address': []}` every time.  I think maybe there is something wrong with the way I'm telling it to extract the data..

**UPDATE:**

It looks like it's not pulling in any data because the request gets cut off at the '#'

````
RESPONSE: <200 https://property.spatialest.com/nc/durham/>
2019-03-16 13:59:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://property.spatialest.com/nc/durham/>
{'address': []}```
````

Comment: That website renders the content with Javascript. Scrapy cannot do that by itself. Have a look at Scrapy Splash: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Answer (score 0):

The site uses additional requests to return data you need.

If you open developer tools you can see request that returns data you need.

Url: `https://property.spatialest.com/nc/durham/data/propertycard`

Method: `POST`

Body: `parcelid=100016&card=&year=&debug%5BcurrentURL%5D=https%3A%2F%2Fproperty.spatialest.com%2Fnc%2Fdurham%2F%23%2Fproperty%2F100016&debug%5BpreviousURL%22%5D=`

Response is json, and you can find all data here.

So you should to make request inside scrapy for take the data